# Can you set a keyboard shortcut for a Windows CMD command?

Tags: windows, cmd, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8.1, taskkill

I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro and would like to know if it's possible to have a keyboard shortcut to run

```
taskkill /F /FI "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING"
```

using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

**SIDE NOTE:**
I have currently have a work-around where I have a batch file (KillTask.bat) with the command and a desktop shortcut to KillTask.bat with the shortcut key set to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

[Screenshot](http://i.snag.gy/Xao42.jpg) 
(Here's a link explaining the work-around)

Is there a more direct method of doing this by way of a keyboard shortcut without the use of desktop shortcuts and batch file?

Comment: I don't think this is the right forum for this type of question. Try http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need the `.bat`. You can do the following:

**1.** Create a shortcut and add the path:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c taskkill /F /FI "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING"
```

**2.** Got to the shortcut properties and put the shorctus key you want: `CTRL + ALT + X`.

And that's all. The only file you need is the shortcut.

The important thing here is that you execute `cmd.exe` with `/c` to specify the command you want to run.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to *eryksun*!

Even better, we can just call `taskkill` directly:

```
C:\Windows\System32\taskkill.exe /F /FI "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING"
```

But still, you need a shortcut file.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. I don't suppose the desktop shortcut could be done without completely?

Comment: @mxrclxst I dont know if there is a shorter way. But there are better forums for this kind of questions, like: [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/). Good luck.